# Are the difference of two vectors orthogonal if the angle between the two vectors approaches 0? (Attempted proof)

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-verification

Suppose that $\vec{a}=(x,y), \vec{a`}=(x', y'), \Delta \vec{a} = (x'-x, y'-y), \theta \rightarrow 0$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{a'},$ and the magnitudes are equal,  $a=a'$

Is it true that $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{a'}$?  I have been using this fact for nearly a year in several physics based courses, but I have no idea how I would prove it.  Below is my attempt at a proof (dot product):

$\vec{a} \cdot \Delta\vec{a} = x(x'-x) + y(y'-y) \rightarrow 0$  Since $\theta \rightarrow 0 \implies \vec{a'} \rightarrow \vec{a}$

But this seems slightly unsatisfactory, because the dot product doesn't say that two vectors are orthogonal if the dot product is near 0, but only equal to 0 exactly. ??

My second attempt uses the cosine law, for what I would assume be a more vigorous proof, taking $\alpha$ for the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\Delta\vec{a}$

$a'^2=a^2+\Delta a^2 - 2a\Delta a\cos\alpha \implies \Delta a^2 = 2a\Delta a\cos\alpha \implies \Delta a = 2a\cos \alpha \implies \frac{\Delta a}{2a} = \cos \alpha$

However, since $\theta \rightarrow 0 \implies$ $\Delta a \rightarrow 0$ then $\alpha = \arccos(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and therefore the vectors are orthogonal.

Please point out any flaws in my proofs, and give me advice.  Thanks!  Another thing I'm sort of iffy about is the statement $\theta \to 0 \implies \Delta \vec{a} \to 0$. Is this correct? It feels weird to use and wrong, because of it being a vector and all

Comment: Can you define what you mean in your title by "Are the difference of two vectors orthogonal"? The difference of two vectors is a vector, and you can't say that a vector is orthogonal.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Suppose you have a vector $\vec{a}$ and then rotate it by $\theta$ to get $\vec{a'}$.  Then $\Delta\vec{a} = \vec{a'} - \vec{a}$.  I meant to say are $\Delta \vec{a}$ and $\vec{a}$ orthogonal? Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Jason No, why would they be? Take $a = (1,0)$ and rotate it by $\pi/2$ to get $a' = (0,1).$ Then $\Delta a = (-1,1)$ is not orthogonal to $a.$

Comment: @A.P. I forgot to mention in my prior comment that $\theta \to 0$, sorry about that.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your $a'$ depends on $\theta,$ and if $\theta \to 0$ then $a' \to a$ so $\Delta a \to 0.$

Comment: In some of my physics text by RC. Hibbeler, it relies on the fact that the two vectors are orthogonal to derive several coordinate formulas for different coordinate systems like circular motion, n-t motion, cylindrical components, etc.  I am trying to prove this is true.  However $\Delta a \to 0$, it is not actually 0 itself.  So couldn't my above two proofs be correct? (At least the last one?) Do you see any errors in them?

Comment: You ask: "Is it true that $a$ is orthogonal to $a'$?" The answer is: it depends on $\theta,$ since $a'$ depends on $\theta.$ (Under the agreement that $a'$ is obtained from $a$ by a rotation of $\theta.$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of imprecision in the result you cited. A correct result would be

> Given a vector $\vec a$ in $\mathbb R^2$, let $\vec a'(\theta)$ be a function such that the angle between  $\vec a'(\theta)$ and $\vec a$ is $\theta$, and $\|\vec a'(\theta)\|=\|\vec a\|$ (notice that for every $\theta$ there's a unique vector satisfying these conditions). If you have a succession $\theta_n$ that converges monotonically to $0$, then the angle between $\Delta \vec a(\theta_n)=\vec a - \vec a'(\theta_n)$ and $\vec a$ tends to $\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$.

In particular it is  false that $\Delta\vec a$ is orthogonal to $\vec a$. It is true **if and only if** $\theta=0$.

Moreover, is correct to say that $\Delta\vec a\to 0$, but is formally more correct to write $\|\Delta \vec a\|\to 0$.

Comment: If it is not too much to ask, are there any specific things that are imprecisie/incorrect? Or is it just that pretty much everything is?

Comment: one thing that is imprecise/incorrect is $\theta\to 0$. You have to specify how $\theta$ converges, otherwise your computations are wrong. For example, if $\theta$ is oscillating arond zero, becoming frequently positive and negative, then there's no convergence in the angle between $\Delta\vec a$ and $\vec a$

Comment: Another thing: You have to specify that $\vec a$ is fixated, otherwise it is false that $\Delta\vec a\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

If I try to understand your question before trying to answer it.

You have a vector $\vec a$ that you rotate with an angle $\theta$ to get the vector $\vec a^\prime$. You then denote $\Delta \vec a$. Your question is: *is the limit of the angle $\widehat{(\vec a, \Delta \vec a)}$ equal to $\pi/2$ when $\theta \to 0$?* Is that your question?

**If yes... Then the answer is yes!**

To prove it, just compute the angles of the isoscele triangle built on $\vec a$ and $\vec a^\prime$.

Comment: Yes, that was my question

Comment: Good! You you have the answer then. Make a good picture and use the fact that the sum of the angles of a triangle is equal to$\pi$.